# puppet: set global timeout for exec

Tags: deployment, puppet

I have a puppet manifest with many operations in exec, here an example of two of them:

```
Exec { path => "/bin" }
exec {
    "apt_get_update":
       timeout => 0,
       command => "/usr/bin/apt-get update";

     "dlmpi":
        timeout => 0,
        command => "wget http://www.open-mpi.org/software/ompi/v1.6/downloads/openmpi-1.6.5.tar.gz",
        cwd     => "/usr/local";
}
```

Is there a way to set the `timeout` globally so I do not have to repeat (and maybe forget) for each operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
Exec { timeout => 0 }
```

More details you will find in article about [resource defaults](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_defaults.html#language:-resource-defaults).

**UPDATE:**
You can also try using puppet [collector.](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_collectors.html) It gives you more control about which resources will have default values: [amending-attributes-with-a-collector](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_resources.html#amending-attributes-with-a-collector).

Comment: This works fine for me, thanks! I wonder if this would also work if I have a `class myclass {}` in my manifest, or would I have to set the timeout in that class as well?